# How to get form id of ninja form before submit form in wordpress using javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ninja-forms

I have created multiple ninja forms. while filling form data how would I know in which form I am filling?

How can I get form id of ninja form before submitting the form in WordPress using javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below code

```
console.log(form.id);
```

you can get form id as soon as form initilised

Answer (score 0):

Add this script to the footer of the page and your form ID will be alerted on successful submission. Not sure why you need this before submission.

```
<script>
var mySubmitController = Marionette.Object.extend( {
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo( Backbone.Radio.channel( 'forms' ), 'submit:response', this.actionSubmit );
  },
  actionSubmit: function( response ) {
      alert(response.data.form_id);
      console.log(response);
  },
});

jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    // Instantiate our custom field's controller, defined above.
    new mySubmitController();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your console? Are you using latest version of the plugin?

Comment: not getting any error, actually its working when click on submit but i want form id before form submit

Comment: Do you need form ID after clicking the submit button just before submission?

Comment: I want form ID before clicking submit button

Comment: There should be some event to get the ID, are you need if someone starts typing in any of the form's fields?

Comment: when the form initialised successfully

Comment: Try `<script>alert(form.id);</script>` in footer.